# Localized decimal numbers format

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I want to print a number in a localized format with a thousands separator and two decimal digits.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pl_PL.UTF-8')

value = 12345.12356

print(f'{value:,.2f}')
print(f'{value:n}')
```

Output:

```
12,345.12
12 345,1
```

The second string is almost what I want, but I cannot find a way to define precision. Cannot use

```
print(f'{value:,.2n}')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(f'{value:,.2n}')
ValueError: Cannot specify ',' with 'n'.
```

while this gives an unexpected result:

```
print(f'{value:.2n}')

1,2e+04
```

How to set the precision to two digits?

Note, I know I can replace the characters in `12,345.12` or use the `decimal` module etc. I just want to know if I can't interpret the documentation correctly, or if the Python developers didn't foresee this need. The latter would be an unpleasant surprise.

Comment: Hmm, I'd have thought `.2n` would have been the right format specifier. This might actually be a Python bug..  it looks like `print(f'{value:.7n}')` gives the "correct" result, which makes me think whatever code is determining the precision is not locale-aware.

Comment: `locale.format_string("%.2f", 12345.12356, grouping=True)` seems to give the desired result.

Comment: This seems to be open issue [bpo33731](https://bugs.python.org/issue33731)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was not aware of it @wim

Comment: @wim - I think that answers my question, unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: There is also [bpo35638](https://bugs.python.org/issue35638) with a pending PR [GH-11405](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/11405).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') # Use '' for auto, or force e.g. to 'en_US.UTF-8'

value = 12345.12356

print(locale.format_string("%.2f", value, grouping=True))
```

**Output: 12,345.12**

#### OR

```
import locale
from babel import numbers

value = 12345.12356

val = numbers.format_decimal(value, locale='pl_PL')
print (val)
```

**Output: 12 345,124**

Comment: @Sabil - Basically, I wanted to use `f"..."` format but it seems impossible for now. Your answer is a nice workaround, surely nicer than replacing characters. BTW, `locale.format_string()` is not depreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you open to use able then I can provide another solution @adam